# Object reference not set to an instance of Object XNA

Tags: c#, xna

Okay so I'm trying to run my xna game and I keep on getting a Null Reference Exception pop up for the following code in my Draw Method of my enemy class yet I have no idea as to what is causing it.

The code in particular I'm referring to is the

```
drawing Origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);
```

.

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        boundingBox.X = (int)position.X;
        boundingBox.Y = (int)position.Y;

        drawingOrigin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);

        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, boundingBox, null, Color.White, orientation, drawingOrigin, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
    }
```

Comment: was texture null when you set a breakpoint and debugged it?

Comment: `Object reference` errors are always the same thing. You are trying to call a property on an object whose value is null.  `texture` being the object, and `Width` being the property.  `null` does not have a property called `Width`, so it throws an error.

Comment: Jonesy yes the drawingOrigin line shows texture as null in breakpoint.

Comment: Now how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Then set a texture... The error message says "Hey, you don't have a texture", if you want to fix it, add one.

Comment: Fixed the problem was problem with LoadContent section in the main game logic.

Comment: @MarcBrooks If you fixed the problem, it would be helpful to answer your own question and provide some details of the solution

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed solution was in the main Game1 logic in

```
Protected Override Content(ContentManager Content)
```

I had called the content as

```
virtualAlien.Content();
```

instead of putting it as

```
virtualAlien.Content(Content);
```